# Add register on create django

Tags: python, django, model, overriding

So i'm trying to do a RESTFULL backend for an app on django. So no views needed, right now i'm adding this at the admin. i have created  2 models 
table 1, and category. Every time i add a table1 row i have to insert 4 categories and budget for every one, initaly 0. i've tried with a method inside table 1 class overriding the save method. and  insert when its inserted but i got an error because referential integrity. i have some quiestions. 
1.- What is the best way to do this? i've seen on_insert event but i've read as well that is not recomended to work with this.
2.- overide the save method leaving blank the reference to the table1? and then update with the last insert? 
3.- other option?

```
class table1(models.Model):
    table1field = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    def  add_cat(self,cat):
        category.objects.create(descripcion_categoria_insumo='category 1', category=cat, budget=0)
        category.save()
        category.objects.create(descripcion_categoria_insumo='category 2', category=cat,budget=0)
        CategoriaInsumo.save()

        pass
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = self.pk is None
        super(table1,self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
        self.add_cat(self.pk)


class category(models.Model):
    desc_category =models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    budget= models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=12,decimal_places=2 ,blank=True)

    category = models.ForeignKey(table1, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.desc_category
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `post_save` [signal from django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/). With signals you can set a function to execute everytime some event happened(here the event is adding new entry to table1).

So you can create a function that everytime table1 objectis created gets called:

```py
from .models import table1, category
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=table1)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # create the categories
    category.objects.create(descripcion_categoria_insumo='category 1',
        category=cat, budget=0)
    .
    .
    .
```

The `instance` is the newly created table1 entry.

Usually this file is located at singals.py and django will not load it by default so you have to edit your apps.py with:

```py
class YouAppConfig(AppConfig):
    .
    .
    .
    def ready():
        import .signals
```